# Windows 10 sleep problems

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, dell-inspiron

I recently reinstalled windows 10 on my laptop. it's well and all, but whenever I put my pc to 'Sleep' mode, it sometimes goes to sleep (ON (state) LED blinking), but there are such cases that the display is black/off, the fans aren't spinning, there is no activity but the led is on, thus the pc is on too, not in sleep. the temporary solution is to force shutdown and reboot my pc, but that's bad.
type your suggestions and thanks

EDIT: here are some pictures https://i.stack.imgur.com/coJ26.jpg

Comment: It's driver's issues. You should update your hardware's drivers.

Comment: Sounds like your machine is not sleeping but hibernating sometimes.  Are you sure you don't have another setting that is set to hibernate as well?

Comment: @Tom before i reinstalled my pc, (it had the same os, win10 x64) the sleep worked but the drivers didn't (the gpu ones)

Comment: @Dale no the pc is not in hibernate mode because in hibernate it should completely shut down but here the led is on, thus the pc is still on
this issue happens sometimes on shutdowns too

Comment: Tell how do you enter the sleep mode. It succeeds in mine installation if I click the use the Start menu > Power > Sleep or press the power button associated with Sleep. Although, PC power button makes a lighter sleep. I cannot wake up by kbd/mouse but sleep in the Start menu makes me hybernate actually. Interestinly that after the power button sleep, PC wakes up and hybernates. But, in neither sleeps nor hibernates on timeout. So, please, tell, which event are you using to enter the problematic sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, sleep and hibernate issues are caused by bad chipset and video drivers.

Try updating video and chipset drivers from the manufacturer website. Also, check the BIOS section to see if there is a new version of the one your computer currently uses. Sometimes, the version of BIOS have a changelog. Check it before upgrading to know if it will correct the mentioned issue.

Warning: Upgrading the BIOS is a delicate procedure that can render your pc unusable. Only do it if you know how to do it.

Comment: the video drivers are fine
for chipset drivers, i have intel chipset and intel management engine interface
and for bios i have A07 and the latest is A08 (dell insyde h2o bios)

Comment: it seems the chipset driver fixed it, thanks for the answer :D

Comment: You welcome :) Cheers

Answer (score 2):

`powercfg -requests` helped to figure out that it was `VIA HD Audio` in my case. Disabling this device solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try going into the power option page and 'choose what the power buttons do' and be sure not to choose hibernate on any of the options.
You may find it useful to turn all options off and only choose sleep for the 'when you close the lid' option.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: I don't have hibernate enabled, i tried turning off fastboot but it didn't work