# PC still working in the sleep mode

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate

After installing a fresh Windows 10, when I click on the sleep mode, just the display gets turned off (becomes black) but it doesn't have any effect on the PC itself.

Everything is working as active (coolers, led indicators, the wifi adapter, etc.) as before going to the sleep mode. And when I press the power button, the display turns on and it's where I left off. So it's not a full sleep mode, is it?

I looked at BIOS settings but I didn't or couldn't find anything. What may be causing this and how can I use *the normal sleep mode*?

Can I enable hibernation along the way?

I read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1087967/windows-10-sleep-problems) but I had installed the latest drivers.

Comment: `when I press the power button, the display turns on and it's where I left off.`, well, that's exactly what sleep mode is for. Are you sure the PC stays active after you press sleep?

Comment: You can enable hibernation in Control Panel > System > Energy > Define what the On and Off buttons do > Enable "Hibernation" to appear in the on/off menu.
Alternatively, on an elevated prompt run `powercfg.exe /hibernation on` to enable it, and, on a regular prompt `shutdown -h` to hibernate your PC

Comment: @DavidDai Yes, I'm pretty sure

Comment: What kind of PC is that? Is it one with the Atom SoC, where the choice of S-states is pretty slim? I have one of them too, and it took some convincing to let it accept hibernation. Plus, how much free space do you have on disk? Hibernation requires a lot of it, depending on how it's set.

Comment: @Didier It's run in the Xeon E5-2620 v2 with 16gb RAM. I have plenty of free space so I don't think it's due to a lack of space.

Comment: Xeons aren't supposed to support sleep/standby, unless your mobo expressly allows it. Have you checked in your BIOS/UEFI what S-states were supported?

Comment: @Didier I really didn't know that. How can I check it?

Comment: Boot in your BIOS/UEFI and check in the Power section if it says anything about the S-states that are supported. If you can enable S1-S2, S3 or S4 from there, you'll be able to set them at OS level. If not, you'll have to do with shutdown and restart, period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, my PC only supports S1 and that's why it is still active in the sleep mode which is the case for S1 mode.